# Inzer single prong belt, need thoughts and/or comments about size issue

Tags: weightlifting, exercise-equipment

I need some solid input from you guys.

My friend let me try his Inzer lever belt, it's a size medium, here's the thing though, the medium measurements for the lever belt are 30 to 33.

When I used the inzer belt, I was basically 1 hole from the tighest setting, if you've used the lever belt it has the plate on the back side that you adjust when you cut/bulk. This setting pinched me a bit more than I liked but I felt like the amount of support I had was perfect.

I ordered a single prong inzer belt, sized medium, because I prefer the prong over the lever. But here's where I made the mistake and just want you guys to confirm or give thoughts. The single prong medium is measured for 33 to 35.

I got my single prong medium today and honestly, it cucked me. I'm like literally one hole away from where I feel like the belt would give me the support I'm looking for but I cannot get it in. So the next hole down I just don't have the abdominal pressure I want compared to the inzer.

So I'm thinking damn, it all makes sense now, after looking at the measurements. The inzer lever belt for me felt the best on nearly the tightest setting, that means the belt for me probably fit in the 30 to 32 range since the 33 would be too big, considering the lowest range of the medium prong is 33 inches, and it's just 1 hole away from probably being a good fit.

The small prong is 28 to 32 inches, so I have the top end of the fit on that belt to fit in the 30 to 32 inch fit on the lever belt. So obviously, I should've gone with the small prong belt to begin with, right? Or am I just retarded and the pronged belts don't give as much support as the lever belt?

I still have at least 3 more holes on the medium belt before it's completely tight. Would I even benefit from a smaller size?

Answer (score 1):

> Or am I just retarded and the pronged belts don't give as much support as the lever belt?

Opinions seem divided on whether a lever and prong can be made just as tight. Some say the lever can be put on tighter, but apparently using a rack as an anchor point when putting on the prong belt can get it just as tight as with a lever.

> I still have at least 3 more holes on the medium belt before it's completely tight. Would I even benefit from a smaller size?

Am I getting this right that you could get the medium on tighter, but the jump in prong holes just isn't as convenient as where you sat with the lever? Of have you actually run out of holes on the medium?

Unless I'm mistaken (someone correct me if so) the hole spacing for lever and prong should be the same. So if it's a matter of sitting somewhere in the middle between two holes, it's due to a slightly different offset with the lever. Maybe you'd be better of with the lever then anyway.

If it's a matter of the medium being too big, a smaller size should do the trick. I'd be really surprised if the suitable sizes don't overlap. There should be some surplus holes. They list them as distinct intervals on the site but I think that's just to find out which size category you fall into depending on measurements. So if you're at the inner limit of a medium you'd probably fit comfortably in small, regardless of some variations depending on meals and progress.

Contact your vendor or Inzer to see about replacing the belt with a smaller size and maybe use the opportunity to get more precise info from them about what would fit you best. I bet they get these questions all the time.

EDIT: oh yeah, I forgot. You could also go for the Inzer PR belt which has a ratchet for being able to adjust as finely as you want, and I suppose a ratchet could be made really tight. But it costs a lot more than the prong or lever belts.